# creating UIButtons in an array and adding them to the MainViewController

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've been working on an app that I manually created a dozen buttons in the IB. I now want to start again, and do everything in code, as I need the number of buttons to be dynamic. I'd also like to do other things like manually control where they appear etc etc.

in `MainViewController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableArray *tiles;
- (IBAction) tilePressed:(id)sender;
- (void) initTiles;
```

in `MainViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initTiles];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setStartButton:nil];
    [self setStopButton:nil];
    [self setTiles:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)initTiles
{
//tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

  for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++) 
  { //I used tiles.count here, but that fails
    UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(count*10+10, 10, 10, 10)];
    [b setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTag:count];
    [b setHidden:NO];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(tilePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
  }
}

-(IBAction)tilePressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button pressed: %i", [sender tag]);
}
```

What I've been trying to do is simply add 5 buttons to the screen. Ideally, I want to create the buttons, have them in an array (NSMutableArray) so that I can manipulate them later, and then throw the `tiles` at the MainViewController. But I'm not even getting the buttons to the controller without the tiles object.

edit: I thought I would add, it's not important they belong to an array, what is important is that I can interact with them later, ie, there will be animations and textual changes to the tiltle, etc etc. The initial problem however, is that they're not displaying on the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually works perfectly, however you can't really tell because:

- The buttons are so small that they are nearly impossible to use
- The buttons are so small that the text title will not show up
- The background color is nil, so it defaults to clear, which makes the entire button invisible in this case.

To make it obvious, just make the buttons bigger and change the background color:

```
-(void)initTiles
{
    //tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    { //I used tiles.count here, but that fails
        UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(count*50+10, 50, 50, 50)];
        [b setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setTag:count];
        [b setHidden:NO];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(tilePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:b];
    }
}
```

Now, as far as adding them to the array:

```
-(void)initTiles
{
    self.tiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

    for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    { //I used tiles.count here, but that fails
        UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(count*50+10, 50, 50, 50)];
        [b setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setTag:count];
        [b setHidden:NO];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(tilePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [b setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        [self.tiles addObject:b];
        [self.view addSubview:b];
    }
}
```

You can then access the buttons by using the array!

Comment: No worries, it isn't obvious until you know!  :-)